# How to "sort" elements of 2 possible values in place in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

Suppose I have a function `f` and array of elements.

The function returns `A` or `B` for any element; you could visualize the elements this way `ABBAABABAA`.

I need to sort the elements according to the function, so the result is: `AAAAAABBBB`

The number of `A` values doesn't have to equal the number of `B` values. The total number of elements can be arbitrary (not fixed). Note that you don't sort chars, you sort objects that have a single char representation.

Few more things:

- the sort should take linear time - `O(n)`,
- it should be performed in place,
- it should be a stable sort.

Any ideas?

---

**Note:** if the above is not possible, do you have ideas for algorithms sacrificing one of the above requirements?

Comment: If you can distinguish/compare two elements, then you can count them.

Comment: I agree. Please read the sentence to the end though :)

Comment: I have read it, it is just unclear: those keys must be comparable with each other, or you need some measurement of equality. In any case, you can count elements equal to n other elements. Maybe you can tell us your exact usecase.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I've updated the description, is it clearer? What I meant is that any `A` != `B`, but `A1` not necessarily  equals `A2`.

Comment: So `A` and `B` are more like categories, and you want to sort by category while keeping elements in stable order?

Comment: I guess it is impossible to do it under such conditions. Linear, Inplace, Stable - you can choose any 2 of them, but not all 3.

Comment: @Geobits yes, you are right

Comment: It is impossible to do with all requirements, without in-place requirement it can be easily done with counting sort.

Comment: I presume that in-place requirement implies "O(1)` space", otherwise you could use radix sort to get a stable sort with `O(N)` time complexity.

Comment: @Groo yes, constant additional memory. The list might be huge.

Answer (score 4):

If it **has** to be linear and in-place, you could do a *semi-stable* version. By semi-stable I mean that `A` or `B` could be stable, but not both. Similar to Dukeling's answer, but you move both iterators from the same side:

```
a = first A
b = first B
loop while next A exists
    if b < a
        swap a,b elements
        b = next B
        a = next A
    else
        a = next A
```

With the sample string `ABBAABABAA`, you get:

```
ABBAABABAA
AABBABABAA
AAABBBABAA
AAAABBBBAA
AAAAABBBBA
AAAAAABBBB
```

on each turn, if you make a swap you move both, if not you just move `a`. This will keep `A` stable, but `B` will lose its ordering. To keep `B` stable instead, start from the end and work your way left.

It may be possible to do it with full stability, but I don't see how.

Comment: this is quite interesting, thanks

Answer (score 2):

A stable sort might not be possible with the other given constraints, so here's an unstable sort that's similar to the partition step of [quick-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort).

1. Have 2 iterators, one starting on the left, one starting on the right.
2. While there's a `B` at the right iterator, decrement the iterator.
3. While there's an `A` at the left iterator, increment the iterator.
4. If the iterators haven't crossed each other, swap their elements and repeat from 2.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say,
  `Object_Array[1...N]`

`Type_A objs are A1,A2,...Ai`

`Type_B objs are B1,B2,...Bj`

`i+j = N`

```
FOR i=1 :N
    if Object_Array[i] is of Type_A
       obj_A_count=obj_A_count+1
    else
       obj_B_count=obj_B_count+1
LOOP
```

Fill the resultant array with `obj_A` and `obj_B` with their respective counts depending on `obj_A > obj_B`

Comment: Unless I'm missing some detail, this is just a counting sort, which won't work given the clarification of the question.

Comment: @Dukeling if we can distinguish two objects why can't we just count them ?

Comment: *"Fill the resultant array with obj_A and obj_B"* - you can't - imagine that `type_X` is one of hash function's result of objects

Comment: @P0W: You can count, but you can not order items this way and fit all requirements (in-place and stable).

Answer (score 0):

The following should work in linear time for a doubly-linked list. Because up to N insertion/deletions are involved that may cause quadratic time for arrays though.

1. Find the location where the first B should be after "sorting". This can be done in linear time by counting As.
2. Start with 3 iterators: iterA starts from the beginning of the container, and iterB starts from the above location where As and Bs should meet, and iterMiddle starts one element prior to iterB.
3. With iterA skip over As, find the 1st B, and move the object from iterA to iterB->previous position. Now iterA points to the next element after where the moved element used to be, and the moved element is now just before iterB.
4. Continue with step 3 until you reach iterMiddle. After that all elements between first() and iterB-1 are As.
5. Now set iterA to iterB-1.
6. Skip over Bs with iterB. When A is found move it to just after iterA and increment iterA.
7. Continue step 6 until iterB reaches end().

This would work as a stable sort for any container. The algorithm includes O(N) insertion/deletion, which is linear time for containers with O(1) insertions/deletions, but, alas, O(N^2) for arrays. Applicability in you case depends on whether the container is an array rather than a list.

Comment: great for Linked Lists, but `O(n^2)` for arrays is not quite it..

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure is a linked list instead of an array, you should be able to meet all three of your constraints. You just skim through the list and accumulating and moving the "B"s will be trivial pointer changes. Pseudo code below:

```
sort(list) {
    node = list.head, blast = null, bhead = null
    while(node != null) {
        nextnode = node.next
        if(node.val == "a") { 
            if(blast != null){              
                //move the 'a' to the front of the 'B' list
                bhead.prev.next = node, node.prev = bhead.prev
                blast.next = node.next, node.next.prev = blast
                node.next = bhead, bhead.prev = node
            }
        }
        else if(node.val == "b") { 
            if(blast == null)
                bhead = blast = node
            else //accumulate the "b"s.. 
                blast = node
        }
```

3

```
        node = nextnode
    }
}
```

So, you can do this in an array, but the memcopies, that emulate the list swap, will make it quiet slow for large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, assuming the array of A's and B's is either generated or read-in, I wonder why not avoid this question entirely by simply applying `f` as the list is being accumulated into memory into two lists that would subsequently be merged.

Otherwise, we can posit an alternative solution in O(n) time and O(1) space that may be sufficient depending on Sir Bohumil's ultimate needs:

Traverse the list and sort each segment of 1,000,000 elements in-place using the permutation cycles of the segment (once this step is done, the list could technically be sorted in-place by recursively swapping the inner-blocks, e.g., ABB AAB -> AAABBB, but that may be too time-consuming without extra space). Traverse the list again and use the same constant space to store, in two interval trees, the pointers to each block of A's and B's. For example, segments of 4,

```
ABBAABABAA => AABB AABB AA + pointers to blocks of A's and B's
```

Sequential access to A's or B's would be immediately available, and random access would come from using the interval tree to locate a specific A or B. One option could be to have the intervals number the A's and B's; e.g., to find the 4th A, look for the interval containing `4`.

For sorting, an array of 1,000,000 four-byte elements (3.8MB) would suffice to store the indexes, using one bit in each element for recording visited indexes during the swaps; and two temporary variables the size of the largest A or B. For a list of one billion elements, the maximum combined interval trees would number 4000 intervals. Using 128 bits per interval, we can easily store numbered intervals for the A's and B's, and we can use the unused bits as pointers to the block index (10 bits) and offset in the case of B (20 bits). 4000*16 bytes = 62.5KB. We can store an additional array with only the B blocks' offsets in 4KB. Total space under 5MB for a list of one billion elements. (Space is in fact dependent on n but because it is extremely small in relation to n, for all practical purposes, we may consider it O(1).)

Time for sorting the million-element segments would be - one pass to count and index (here we can also accumulate the intervals and B offsets) and one pass to sort. Constructing the interval tree is O(nlogn) but n here is only 4000 (0.00005 of the one-billion list count). Total time O(2n) = O(n)

Answer (score -1):

This should be possible with a bit of dynamic programming.

It works a bit like counting sort, but with a key difference. Make arrays of size n for both a and b count_a[n] and count_b[n]. Fill these arrays with how many As or Bs there has been before index i.

After just one loop, we can use these arrays to look up the correct index for any element in O(1). Like this:

```
int final_index(char id, int pos){
    if(id == 'A')
      return count_a[pos];
    else
      return count_a[n-1] + count_b[pos];
}
```

Finally, to meet the total O(n) requirement, the swapping needs to be done in a smart order. One simple option is to have recursive swapping procedure that doesn't actually perform any swapping until both elements would be placed in correct final positions. EDIT: This is actually not true. Even naive swapping will have O(n) swaps. But doing this recursive strategy will give you absolute minimum required swaps.

Note that in general case this would be very bad sorting algorithm since it has memory requirement of O(n * element value range).

Comment: *Make arrays of size n for both a and b count_a[n] and count_b[n]* this sounds like `O(n)` memory :(

Comment: Still it's in-place, stable and linear. If sizeof(your_object) >> sizeof(int), it shouldn't be too bad that you have to allocate few integer arrays.

Comment: To me, "in-place" loosely translates to "O(1) extra space".

Comment: @SanttuKeskinen If I can use `O(n)` space then I can simply create 2 arrays of `n` size, copy all `A`s to first (in order of appearance), `B`s to 2nd and then merge. Simpler.

Comment: What are these "elements" that you are storing? It just seems strange to me that you can't afford 32 or what ever extra bits per "element". Heck, you could use the same array where you store the IDs as extra space and bring that even lower, say 32-8=24. These "elements" must be really space efficient!